# How to update matplotlib quiver scale in animation with changing amount of points

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, scale

I'm trying to animate a Matplotlib quiver. On every step amount of points, which are shown, is changing. This fact ruins the 'xy' scale, and I get errors 'Operands with different shapes cannot be broadcast together', where one shape belongs to x array in the first frame, and the other to current. When I change scale to 'inches' everything works fine.

So my question is: can I modify quiver scale in animation, so that it could properly handle new amount of points?

Thanks for any help.